# Throw a compiler error when unsupported class method is used

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance

I have a practical problem here. I need to expand our class for data table. The main class is abstract interface:

```
class TableInterface {
    abstract void something( some arguments ) = 0;
    abstract void something_2( some arguments ) = 0;
    // many more follow ...
      ...
    abstract int MyNewMethod() = 0;
}
```

There's about 6 implementation of those class. I only need it in one implementation and this won't probably change for a while. The new method makes sense in all sub-classes and could be implemented. I am left with this options right now:

- Actually implement the method for all 6 classes. This is not a technical problem but means a lot of work that will never be put to use. The method **does make sense** for all subclasses - problem isn't in design but in my laziness.
- Leave empty method body. That's nasty.

  ```
      abstract int MyNewMethod() {return -1;}
  ```
- Throw exception on use or use `assert`:

  ```
      abstract int MyNewMethod() {throw std::std::runtime_error("Not implemented!");}
        -- or --
      abstract int MyNewMethod() {assert("Not implemented yet!" && false);}
  ```

The problem is that apart of my option one, all the other ones can cause problems to other developpers, who may compile the code unsuspecting that the method body is not implemented.

Can I have compiler raise an error when class method is *used*?

Comment: What if you only declare the member function and not implement it. This way it would compile if it's not used and it will produce a linker error if it is used.

Comment: Linker errors are very confusing, I'd rather avoid them anywhere anytime.

Comment: Actually in your case it shouldn't be so confusing. You would get linker errors along the lines of `undefined reference to TableInterface::method`, with the name of the object file that has the reference

Answer (score 1):

You could try something along the lines of:

```
class TableInterface 
{
public:
    ...
    virtual int MyNewMethod()
    {
#ifndef MYNEWMETHOD_ALLOWED
        static_assert(false, "MyNewMethod not implemented");
#endif
        ...
    }
    ...
};
```

Then, when compiling your own code you would include the `-DMYNEWMETHOD_ALLOWED` define switch. Anybody else compiling their own work, not knowing about this define, would get a compile error.